# Creating links within a document using a preexisting Table of Contents

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, tableofcontents

I've got a large number of OCRed documents that have been partially marked up. I'm trying to create working links within the table of contents. The table of contents are formatted

```
<document>
  <text>
     <list>
        <item>Chapter 1<ref>7</ref></item>
        <item>Chapter 2<ref>27</ref></item>
        <item>Chapter 3<ref>54</ref></item>
        <item>Chapter 4<ref>77</ref></item>
     </list>
     <body>
      OCRED text <pb n="7-8" xml:id="VAB0003"/> OCRED text
     </body>   
</document>
```

Is there a way to test if the value of ref is the same as part of the value of @n in pb and then if so pull the value of @xml:id and use that in the ref element?
Is there a less convoluted way of accomplishing this?

Comment: try to make your title short and descriptive!!

Comment: Will the **n** attribute always consist of two parts, or can it have multiple hyphens in?

Comment: it represents page numbers. it will sometimes consist of two parts formatted n-n (or nn-nn or nnn-nnn) and sometimes only a single part with no dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="ref*">
  <xsl:variable name="page" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="target" 
                select="//pb[contains(
                        concat(' ',translate(@n,'-',' '),' '), 
                        concat(' ',$page,' '))]/@xml:id"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="$target">
      <xsl:attribute name='target'>
        <xsl:value-of select="$target"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The complicated concatenations are there in the definition of `target` to ensure that you match on a full token of the page number; in XSLT 2.0 it can be done a little more gracefully and without the concats, but not much more succinctly.

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, the [Stack Overflow convention](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) is for you to click on the check-mark outline next to the answer.  (Corny as it sounds, the reputation points you cause the system to give the author of the answer, when you do that, turn out to be surprisingly motivational.)